# Required to create a OpenERP/Odoo POS category and product associated to this category

Tags: odoo

I'm using OpenERP POS 7 latest version. I need help for create a product under specific category.

Use Case: I like to create a new category and create a product for that new category.

Steps Followed:

Step 1: I create a Category  from "Point Of Sale" -> "Products" -> "Product Category" -> "Create"

Steps 2: When I create a product from "Point Of Sale" -> "Products" -> "Product" -> "Create", I'm not seeing the already created category in step 1. In Product creation screen again we can create a new category but category created from product screen in not displayed in sales screen

Also I observe that in Odoo pos demo I can see the category labeled as  "Pos/Public Product Categories" instead of "Product Category" is there any difference in these?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you haven't provided these rights to the (current) user, So  give user all the privileges so that he can find the added category.

For this navigate to Settings > Configuration > Users > Select the user > Edit > select Access rights > Check Products variants.